# How to enforce a context bound on a wildcard in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, wildcard, implicit

I have an implicit helper set up like this:

```
trait Helper[T] {
  def help(entry: T): Unit
}

object Helpers {
  implicit object XHelper extends Helper[X] {
    override def help(entry: X): Unit = {println("x")}
  }
  implicit object YHelper extends Helper[Y] {
    override def help(entry: Y): Unit = {println("y")}
  }

  def help[T](entry: T)(implicit helper: Helper[T]): Unit = {
    helper.help(entry)
  }
}
```

I would like to set up a collection of elements and run `help` on each of them. However, the following gives a compiler error because we can't guarantee all elements have matching `Helper`s:

```
val data = Seq[_](new X(), new Y())
data.foreach(entry => Helpers.help(entry))
```

If we had a generic type `T` we could enforce the implicit constraint on it with `[T: Helper]`, but that doesn't work on `_`. How can I enforce that each element of `data` has a matching `Helper`?

Comment: Are you able to extend types `X` and `Y` with a new trait, say `trait HasHelp`?

Comment: No, unfortunately that code is outside my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with type like `Seq` since it is only parametrized for one element type that is common for all its elements.

However, you can achieve this with [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) HLists and polymorphics functions (Poly):

```scala
class X
class Y

trait Helper[T] {
  def help(entry: T): Unit
}

object Helpers {
  implicit object XHelper extends Helper[X] {
    override def help(entry: X): Unit = println("x")
  }

  implicit object YHelper extends Helper[Y] {
    override def help(entry: Y): Unit = println("y")
  }
}

import shapeless._

object helper extends Poly1 {
  implicit def tCase[T: Helper]: Case.Aux[T, Unit] = 
    at(implicitly[Helper[T]].help(_))
}

val hlist = new X :: new Y :: HNil
hlist.map(helper)

// Output:
x
y
```

Comment: It surprises me that it's impossible though, since I can do things like `Seq[_ <: SomeType]`. It feels like there should be an operator for this, or is there a reason why there couldn't be one?

Comment: Context bound like `T: Helper` is just a syntactic sugar for `(implicit ev: Helper[T])` in a method, so I'm not sure how it could even work with parametrization of values.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala context bound like `class A[T: Typeclass]` is just syntactic sugar for `class A[T](implicit ev: Typeclass[T])`. Unlike `T <: Base` or `T >: Super`, context bound is not really a part of a type signature, so you can't have a signature like `val b: Box[T: Typeclass]`.

If you want to run typeclass operations on elements of some container, you'd have to pack relevant typeclass instances together with the values in the container.

A possible implementation of this may look as follows:

```
import language.higherKinds
import language.implicitConversions

// Class that packs values with typeclass instances
class WithTC[T, TC[_]](t: T)(implicit tc: TC[T]) {
  // Some helper methods to simplify executing typeclass operations
  // You may just make `t` and `tc` public, if you wish.
  def apply[U](op: (TC[T], T) => U) = op(tc, t)
  def apply[U](op: T => TC[T] => U) = op(t)(tc)
}
object WithTC {
  // Implicit conversion to automatically wrap values into `WithTC`
  implicit def apply[T, TC[_]](t: T)(implicit tc: TC[T]): WithTC[T, TC] =
    new WithTC(t)(tc)
}
```

Then you can make a sequence with existentially typed elements:

```
import Helpers._
val data: Seq[(T WithTC Helper) forSome { type T }] = Seq(new X(), new Y())
```

And execute typeclass operations on the sequence elements:

```
// The following lines produce equivalent results
data.foreach(_(_ help _))
data.foreach(_(t => implicit tc => Helpers.help(t)))
data.foreach(_(t => Helpers.help(t)(_)))
```